# On an html/php file upload page, can you allow users to select files for upload one at a time without overwriting the previously selected file?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a form that allows users to upload multiple files, and it works perfectly.

My issue is this - when a user clicks 'select file', chooses a file, then clicks 'open', the file appears ready for upload. However, if the user then clicks 'select file' again, and chooses another file to upload, when they click 'open' the first file is overwritten.

The only way to upload multiple files is to select them all at once, and only click 'open' one time.

I'm wondering if there is any setting or anything that can be changed so that when a user selects a second file after already selecting a first, the second will not overwrite the first and instead will be added so that both files will be uploaded.

Basically, I want the user to be able to upload multiple files but select them one at a time.

Thanks!

I feel like I should clarify because it seems like I didn't explain the issue very well. I'm using a form that allows multiple files to be attached (in the same input), and it's working perfectly. However, it seems that the way browsers handle multiple file inputs is to allow multiple files to be selected for uploading all at one time only - if the user selects one at a time (and clicks 'open' for each), the last file selected (or the last group selected) is the only one attached to the form for uploading. Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is my code:

HTML (only the relevant parts):

```
<form style="margin-left:10px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_page_form" name="contact_page_form">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple />
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (($_POST["Name"] != '') && (isset($_POST["E-mail"])) && ($_POST["E-mail"] != '') && (!filter_var($_POST["E-mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false))
    {

        $uploadMsg = '';
        $uploadedFilesString = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++)
        {
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
            if ($tmpFilePath != "")
            {
                $newFilePath = "./userUploads/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                $currFileType = pathinfo($newFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if (file_exists($newFilePath)) {
                    $newFilePath = "./userUploads/" . date("U") . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                }
                $newFilePath = str_replace(' ', '', $newFilePath);

                if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1024000000) {
                    $uploadMsg .= 'File ' . $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i] . ' is too large.<br/>';
                    $form_submit_fail = 1;
                    continue;
                }

                $currFileType = strtolower($currFileType);
                if($currFileType != "jpg" && $currFileType != "png" && $currFileType != "jpeg" && $currFileType != "gif" && $currFileType != "mp4" && $currFileType != "avi" && $currFileType != "mov" && $currFileType != "m4v" ) {
                    $uploadMsg .= 'File ' . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i] . ' is not an allowed filetype.<br/>';
                    $form_submit_fail = 1;
                    continue;
                }

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath))
                {
                  $uploadedFilesString .= 'Attached File: ' . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i] . ' <a href="http://www.gopherhawk.com/' . substr($newFilePath, 2) . '">Link</a><br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats just bad coding on your part. Show the code you wrote in the upoad script if you actually want any help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just added my code. I didn't think this had to do with my php code, I thought it was an issue that's occurring on the front-end before the files are sent to the upload script. I'm able to upload multiple files with no problem. The issue is with the way they are 'attached' to the form. If this is an issue with my php code, I'd appreciate some help fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I get this straight: you are using HTML `file`-type `input` with `multiple` attribute, meaning you can send multiple files on the same `input`.

**That works this way:**

> The multiple attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the user is allowed to enter more than
>   one value in the  element.
>
> Note: The multiple attribute works with the following input types:
>   email, and file.
>
> Tip: For `<input type="file">`: to select multiple files, hold down the
>   CTRL or SHIFT key while selecting.

So if you're trying to upload multiple files and **assign them to the same `file`-type `input`**, it's only natural it gets overwritten every time you manage to select different files again.

If you want to select one file at a time, insert multiple `file`-type `inputs` in your `form`. If you have no idea how many files may be attached, deal with `input` generation dynamically with Javascript or even PHP, if it isn't mandatory that your form page is pure front-end.

Comment: Great. That's really all I wanted to know, was whether or not it could be done using HTML file-type input with multiple attribute. I thought there might be a flag that you could add to the field to make it work differently. I appreciate your help. I will work on a javascript solution as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function for that to show another block for adding file. However, this is not very practical. In my opinion, automatic verification of file and uploading via AJAX will be better solution.

Comment: First _This is a comment and not an answer._ Second _The OP cannot work out how to uniquely name a file upload, do you really think javascript and JQuery is a sensible suggestion_

Comment: Uploading multiple files separately is bad idea.